# How to increase row height of listview in report style?

Tags: delphi, listview, row-height

I need to add just 2px :) to a height of a row in a list view (a custom drawn progress bar is too narrow now).

There are two good answers [Change Listview item height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569779/change-listview-item-height), http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=49939, but I couldn't do it.

I know that it is possible to do with an image list, but I have already 16x16 images :)

Can anybody help me?
I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Respond to the `CN_MEASUREITEM` control notification message, as follows:

```
type
  TListView = class(ComCtrls.TListView)
  private
    procedure CNMeasureItem(var Message: TWMMeasureItem); message CN_MEASUREITEM;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...

procedure TListView.CNMeasureItem(var Message: TWMMeasureItem);
begin
  inherited;
  Inc(Message.MeasureItemStruct.itemHeight, 2);
end;
```

Note: this message will only be send if the `OwnerDraw` property is true.

Comment: Wow! Thanks!!! I saw a source code of TMS' TAdvListView and this message `CNDrawItem(var Message: TWMDrawItem);` is handled too (the link delphipages has the same code as in TMS). Why?

Comment: Dunno TAdvListView. The default TListView has the OnDrawItem event already.

Comment: id doesn't matter much :) It works!!! You are a good programmer & as a person! Thanks!

Comment: One "small" and funny bug :) -> `ListView1.Align:=alClient;` please add items, resize a window and see what will happen :) How to fix? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you probably are better off with `Message.MeasureItemStruct.itemHeight := 21;`.

Comment: This doesn't work with a `TCustomListView` - can't seem to find the way of doing this.

Comment: @James Strange. Maybe the why is worth its own question.

Comment: great solution! is there any way to change the header row's height?

Comment: @tcxbalage Not easy. The fun starts by retrieving the header control with the [ListView_GetHeader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_getheader) macro, but simply setting its height won't do. You have to respond to all the messages resetting the height as well as adjusting the list view's client rect. If you are really interested, then you should ask a new question linking to this one, because a complete answer would not fit here.

Answer (score 8):

A quick and dirty alternative without writing any code would be to add a TImageList, set its width to 1 and its height to whatever you want the lines height to be and assign it to the SmallImages of the listview.

Comment: I don't think it's a "dirty" alternative, works perfectly without side effects!

Comment: I am using actually SmallImages property, thus it is not a good solution for me. But, as found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6564492/1960514, you can use also StateImages for this purpose!