# Delphi firemonkey ListView Item.Height

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

**UPDATE : My question is about FMX listView not about VCL one , that's to explaine  that my Question isn't a duplicate of this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569779) .**

i'm trying to accomplish a kind of ListView Items hide mechanism by setting ListView.Item[x].Height:=0 , But that didn't give any result

**Adding Items :**

```
 procedure TForm6.AddItemsClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
    I:Integer;
    AItem: TListViewItem;
    begin
        for I := 0 to 5 do
         Begin
           AItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
           //with AItem do
               //   Text := 'Text';
         End;
    end;
```

**Trying to hide Items :**

```
 procedure TForm6.HideItemsClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
    I:Integer;
    begin
         ListView1.BeginUpdate;
         try
         for I := 0 to ListView1.ItemCount-1 do
         // ListView1.Items.Item[I].Height:=0; // doesn't give any result
          ListView1.Items.Item[I].Height:=1;
         finally
           ListView1.EndUpdate;
         end;

    end;
```

[image: The Result]

Any help to fix this please ? or why

```
ListView1.Items.Item[I].Height:=0;
```

Has no effect ?

Comment: Remove `ListView1.Items.Item[I].Height:=1;`

Comment: @Sami, if i remove that what will be the result ?

Comment: All items height = 0 .

Comment: @Sami , if you read my question : `ListView1.Items.Item[I].Height:=0;` will not give any result ( no effects )

Comment: Hmmm if you need to hide all items , why you don't hide the list ?

Comment: @Sami , I don't want to hide the whole list but only some of its items .

Comment: It is hardcoded not to accept negative or zero height. The gray lines you see are separator lines. But I think you should consider not to keep your data in the control. Instead (speaking only about strings now) in e.g. a TStringList and signal the `ListView` to update itself when the content in the `StringList` is changed.

Comment: Don't let a TListView become the container of your _actual_ data. Use the TListView as a _dumb_ data displayer. Hold your data in a non-ui class (ie list of something, array of something) and then have your TListView display only the elements you require